# Want to use this `react-native-audio-recorder-player` library for audio recorder in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Want to implement audio recorder with this react-native-audio-recorder-player library in react native project it not runs my project.

My project details:-

react-native:0.63.4
using jdk-11

Install react-native-audio-recorder-player this library then it returns error

../node_modules\react-native-audio-recorder-player\android\src\main\java\com\dooboolab.audiorecorderplayer\RNAudioRecorderPlayerModule.kt: (67, 29): 'constructor MediaRecorder()' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

and

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-audio-recorder-player:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 17' using tool chain: 'JDK 11 (11)'.

Comment: Try downgrading `react-native-audio-recorder-player`.

Comment: Already download library ,but it not support in my react-native project ,once library installed in project then it stop running  and returns above error which I mentioned